# Mongoose - Calculate or merge value of data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new with mongoose. Can mongoose do something like i want to see how many linkview of James where store is Red only . `The expected outcome should be linkview = 2 because 1+1`. Please help

So this is `User` schema

```
{        
  "_id": "234",
  "name": "James",
  "__v": 0,
}
```

So this is `affiliatelink` schema

```
{        
  "_id": "11",
  "store": "Red",
  "linkview": "1",
  "date": 12/12/12,
  "affiliate": "James"
},
{        
  "_id": "22",
  "store": "Red",
  "linkview": "1",
  "date": 13/12/12,
  "affiliate": "James"
},
{        
  "_id": "33",
  "store": "Blue",
  "linkview": "1",
  "date": 13/12/12,
  "affiliate": "James"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count the value of linkview or want to aggregate the data?

Comment: @Bibek, aggregate sir. Just to update i have found solution for this problem. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an aggregation you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "affiliate": "James",
      store: "Red"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "linkview_count": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

The result will be:

```
[
  {
    "linkview_count": 2
  }
]
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/lPPhv9_w4iT

Comment: Thank you. i have a solution already using similar method as you.